# how to copy large database which occupies much memory from assets folder to my application?

Tags: android, database

I am developing an application in which I have to use existing database but when I try to copy small data base It is copying easily but when I try to copy my database which is of 2.5mb it is not copying some times it shows o bytes of memory copied I have followed some tutorial for eg http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ is one of them but I can not resolve it. Can any body give me suggestion or any useful tutorial that can help me resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `aapt` compressing the file in your assets folder. See links below for various solutions:

[How to read LARGE Sqlite file to be copied into Android emulator, or device from assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928214/how-to-read-large-sqlite-file-to-be-copied-into-android-emulator-or-device-from)

http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/

Comment: Sir I have used one of answer from your suggestion https://gist.github.com/717801  I am not able to open the data base. but do you have any idea and thanks for help

Comment: Then why not try one of the less code intensive solutions, like renaming your file database to .mp3 or .jet to prevent aapt compression?