# [Android SDK]Can't copy external database (13MB) from Assets

Tags: android, database, large-files

I need a list of italian words for a game I'm developing but I can't actually make it copy my database from assets. I tried quitea lot of solutions I found on the website, such as:

1. [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://goo.gl/pvog)
2. [how to copy large database which occupies much memory from assets folder to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008327/how-to-copy-large-database-which-occupies-much-memory-from-assets-folder-to-my-a)
3. [Load files bigger than 1M from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928214/how-to-read-large-sqlite-file-to-be-copied-into-android-emulator-or-device-from)

But I had no luck, it keeps on giving me [this error](http://pastebin.com/Qmamistc) on the line

```
os.write(buffer, 0, len);
```

but I can't understand why. Here's the [function's code](http://pastebin.com/eLqnL2dc) and the [constants](http://pastebin.com/D8uhNYRV) I'm using.
A strange thins is that my database stops copying after 11.45MB, just 1 MB away from the goal.

Can someone help me solve this? Many thanks :)

Comment: Visit this Q and A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard

Comment: Error is that you don't check `len` before you use it in the `write`. `len` is `-1` at the end of the stream and that is no valid index. Use @gtumca-MAC's while loop next time you copy streams and you are safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which has a debugged version of the package-the-database-with-the-app logic, so you do not need to mess with any of this yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip, I'll test it out right now :) Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all by default asset folder supports max size for db file is 1mb.

You need to divide your database into parts.

[Download **HJSplit**](http://hjsplit.en.softonic.com/download) and divide your database into small parts
like 13MB = 13 parts each of 1MB.

demoDB.sqlitedb= 13MB
then

```
demodb..sqlitedb.001
demodb..sqlitedb.002
demodb..sqlitedb.003
demodb..sqlitedb.004
...
...
demodb..sqlitedb.013
```

Then use the following code to merge your database.

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        String[] files = am.list("");
        Arrays.sort(files);
        int r;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            InputStream is = am.open("demoDB.sqlitedb.00" + i);
            while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            }
            Log.i("BABY_DATABASE_HELPER", "Copying the database (part " + i
                    + " of 9)");
            is.close();
        }
        os.close();
    }
```

Comment: I read somewhere that the limitation does not apply on any Android 2.3 system, that's why I didn't split, but thanks for the tip :) :)

Comment: Quite right, totally forgot about older version presence in the market :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    String[] files = am.list("");
    Arrays.sort(files);
    int r;
    for (int i = 1; i <=21; i++) {
        InputStream is;

        if ( i < 10){
            System.out.println("coping file demoDB.sqlitedb.00"+i );
             is = am.open("demoDB.sqlitedb.00" + i);
        }else{
            System.out.println("coping file demoDB.sqlitedb.0"+i );
             is = am.open("demoDB.sqlitedb.0" + i);
       }
        while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, r);
        }
        is.close();
    }
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered but I ran into something like this while creating tests where I wanted to store a particular database with faults in it to test bad data.  Problem was test database was not found at all in the assets.  To even see it I had to do this:

```
InputStream is = mContext.createPackageContext("com.activities.tests", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY).getAssets().open("mydb.db");
```

By ignoring the security you can see it and then take the inputstream and save it to an external directory.

Comment: Good call, I'll test it out as soon as possible