# Big DB file support on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard, fat32, fat

We all know that Android doesn't support any filesystem for SD cards except FAT. 
I have huge DB sqlite file (approx. 9 Gb) and I would like to work with the file on my mobile device, but now it's impossible. Can I divide the file into some smaller files (with same DB tables structure, of course) and then with any software (JDBC extend module or something similar) assemble these files into one DB on logical level. Does anyone know this java-software/library? or it's only my beatific vision? :)

Thanks.

Comment: I think its 9-MB not GB am i rite ?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419043/1289716

Comment: No :) 9 GB and more, FAT doesn't support file size more than 3 GB

Comment: Does your android device have 9 GB internal space ?

Comment: SD Card - 32 GB. Everyone can use SD card space for manipulation with sqlite files.