# Database not working in exported apk?

Tags: java, android

I export my application to .apk file, sign it then install it. But when I run my App, it displays an error because there's no data in my database. The database was created as a new one when I installed the application, so all the data were lost! How can I include database data when exporting an Android application? I check it an eclipse DDMS File explorer.the database does not have a any tables. it's copying database partily in my asset folder.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to keep copy of your database in `asset` folder and copy your database when your application get installed at **first time**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419043/1289716) code for How to copy your database

Hope this will help you...

Comment: i copy and paste a database in my asset folder. but not full db store in emulator device. i check it in DDMS  device file explorer

Comment: 4.00kb. in my code i copide the dp from asset folder and stored in data/data/mypackage/database folder.and run it.in  finally  coping 3kb only device

Comment: i create a table using sqllitemanager gui tool..sqllite version 3.it's have any issue